# Any documentation about pure React Native without using EXPO?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to learn React Native but, without using EXPO

Why do i not using EXPO? (source: Youtube Channel "McAbout Digital")

1. Lack of support for geolocation
2. No support for Payment API
3. Slow image rendering
4. Limited access to Firebase setting
5. Advanced animation support

Wherever i google about React Native the EXPO is always there too.
I'm looking for pure react native documentation/tutorial

Comment: Apart from the initial setup, coding with or without Expo is exactly the same. The official documentation mentions Expo only on the first page and even that has a "native code" alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from project setup almost everything is same in the docs for both versions,
but if you are looking for a good tutorial series you can start learning by
[UDEMY - React Native Practical Guid](https://www.udemy.com/react-native-the-practical-guide/) which is a paid course but worth it.